# How can i safe the file paths from dropzone image upload in DataBase?

Tags: javascript, php, database, forms, dropzone

I have a form with a dropzone image upload. I want to write the values from the form and the file path of the multiple images from dropzone upload together in the database. So i can later display the form datas together with the images. I have no idea how to realize it.

```
<form id="checkout" method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data" action="/index.php">

  <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Projektname" value="" />
    <br /> 

    <div id="error_message></div>
    <br /> 

    <input name="lage" id="lage" type="text" placeholder="Lage" value="" /> 
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>

  <div style="width:50%; float:left;">       
    <textarea name="beschreibung" class="form-name" id="beschreibung" style="height:100px;" type="text" placeholder="Beschreibung" value=""></textarea> 
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>

  <h2>Bilder:</h2>

  <div class="dropzone dropzone-previews" id="myDropzone"></div>

  <input type="submit" onClick="return validation();" id="submit-form" class="hidden" style="display:none;" />

</form>
```

```
function validation() {   
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var lage = document.getElementById("lage").value;
  var beschreibung = document.getElementById("beschreibung").value;
  var error_message = document.getElementById("error_message");
  error_message.style.padding = "5px";

  if(name.length <5) {
    text = "Bitte gib einen Projektnamen ein.";
    error_message.innerHTML = text;
    return false;  
  } else {
    text = "";
    error_message.innerHTML = text;
  }

  /* ##### Projekt anlegen ##### */
  var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var params = 'name='+name+'&beschreibung='+beschreibung+'&lage='+lage;

  xml.open('GET', 'sendRegisterData.php?name='+name+'&beschreibung='+beschreibung+'&lage='+lage, false);
  xml.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencode');
  xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
      // alert(xml.responseText);
    }
  }
  xml.send(params);

  return true;
}
```

SendRegisterData.php

```
<?php
include "Config.php";


$name = $_GET["name"];
$beschreibung = $_GET["beschreibung"];
$lage = $_GET["lage"];
$data = $_GET["data"];

$primid =  $_GET["primid"];


$conn = new mysqli(Config::getHost(), Config::getUsername(), Config::getPassword(), Config::getDatabase());

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Projekt(name, beschreibung, lage, data, primid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $name, $beschreibung, $lage, $data, $primid);

$stmt->execute(); // Daten in Datenbanken senden

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Upload.php

```
<?php


$target_dir = 'uploads/';   //2

$target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);          //3             

$msg = "";

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_file)){
  $msg = "erfolgreich hochgeladen";
} else {
  $msg = "Fehlgeschlagen - Bilder konnten nicht hochgeladen werden.";
}

Include "Config.php";


$primid = $_GET["primid"];


$conn = new mysqli(Config::getHost(), Config::getUsername(), Config::getPassword(), Config::getDatabase());

$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Projekt SET bilder = ? WHERE primid = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $target_file, $primid );

$stmt->execute(); // Daten in Datenbanken senden

mysqli_close($conn);

echo $msg;
exit;
?>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Why do you think you can read the complete path and not only the filename and extension? Be sure to test your solution in multiple browsers.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, thank you for your reply. My file path is $target_file which i need to write in the database. But the upload is working and i get the file path to write it in the database, but my problem is, that i can upload mutiple files with dropzone but with my script i have just one file path in the database in the end.